# When using C++ pointer -> is there implicit Data type conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, implicit-conversion

I am trying to debug someone else's code.

There is a struct with elements of various size including a member defined as

`uint16_t attempts`

elsewhere this element is accessed thus

`int x = handle->attempts;`

int in my system is 32 bits

Is it safe to assume that 2 bytes are loaded from the position pointed to in the struct (uint16_t) and implicitly convert to int (4 bytes).

Or is it possible that the 4 bytes pointed to are loaded as an int (in this case an amalgamation of 2 uint16_t members)?

Comment: Only the two bytes will be converted.  A compiler that tried to use 4 bytes would be considered broken.

Comment: More generally, for any code `int x = (expression);`, the `int` does not determine how `(expression)` is evaluated.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one language and delete the other tag.

Comment: So in summary would it be true in essence to say that handle->attempts has regard to how attempts was defined in whatever struct is pointed to and fetches the appropriate number of bytes. Then, and only then, an implicit conversion (if needed) takes place according to the type of the recipient variable.

Comment: That's accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int x = handle->attempts;` is a declaration with an initialization. In this declaration, `handle->attempts` is an *initializer*, per the grammar in C 2018 6.7 1. An *initializer* is an *assignment-expression*, per C 2018 6.7.9 1, and so rules for expression evaluation will be used.

The expression `handle->attempts` designates the `uint16_t` member named `attempts` of the structure pointed to by `handle`. In other words, it is an lvalue for the member. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, this lvalue is converted to the value stored in the designated object. Thus, the C standard says the bytes representing this object are read and interpreted according to the `uint16_t` type.

Then a rule for initialization in C 2018 6.7.9 11 tells us this value is used as the initial value for the object being defined, `x`, using the same constraints and conversions as for simple assignment.

C 2018 6.5.16.1 specifies simple assignment. Paragraph 2 says “the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.” Thus, the **value** we have obtained from the initializer is converted to the type of `x`, `int`, and that bytes representing that value in the type `int` are stored in `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Converting an integer value to another integer type is guaranteed to result in the same value as long as the target type can represent the value in question. A 4 byte `int` will be able to represent all values of `std::uint16_t`.